# Programmatically invoke Annotation Processors

Tags: java, annotations, annotation-processing

This is the first time I am writing a Annotation Processor and I want to invoke it programmatically. Is it possible?

I have written small code for processor:

```
@SupportedAnnotationTypes({"app.dev.ems.support.annotation.HBMModel"})
public class HBMModelProcessor extends AbstractProcessor {

    @Override
    public boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations, RoundEnvironment roundEnv) {
        Set<? extends Element> elements = roundEnv.getElementsAnnotatedWith(HBMModel.class);
        System.out.println(elements);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Now If I want to invoke the process method, then how can I do this? Can I do it in following way:

```
HBMModelProcessor modelProcessor = new HBMModelProcessor();
modelProcessor.process(annotations, roundEnv)
```

Any information will be very helpful to me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can call the Java compiler with annotation processors programmatically, inside the same process, like this:

```
import com.sun.tools.javac.processing.PrintingProcessor;
import fi.jumi.actors.generator.JavaSourceFromString;
import org.junit.*;
import org.junit.rules.TemporaryFolder;

import javax.annotation.processing.Processor;
import javax.tools.*;
import javax.tools.JavaCompiler.CompilationTask;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;

import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.is;

public class ExampleTest {

    @Rule
    public final TemporaryFolder tempDir = new TemporaryFolder();

    @Test
    public void example() throws IOException {
        JavaFileObject src = new JavaSourceFromString(
                "com.example.GuineaPig",
                "package com.example;\n" +
                "public interface GuineaPig {\n" +
                "    void foo();\n" +
                "}"
        );
        compile(new PrintingProcessor(), src);
    }

    private void compile(Processor processor, JavaFileObject... compilationUnits) throws IOException {
        JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
        DiagnosticCollector<JavaFileObject> diagnostics = new DiagnosticCollector<JavaFileObject>();
        StandardJavaFileManager fileManager = compiler.getStandardFileManager(diagnostics, null, null);
        fileManager.setLocation(StandardLocation.CLASS_OUTPUT, Arrays.asList(tempDir.getRoot()));

        CompilationTask task = compiler.getTask(null, fileManager, diagnostics, null, null, Arrays.asList(compilationUnits));
        task.setProcessors(Arrays.asList(
                processor
        ));
        boolean success = task.call();
        for (Diagnostic<? extends JavaFileObject> diagnostic : diagnostics.getDiagnostics()) {
            System.err.println(diagnostic);
        }
        assertThat("compile succeeded", success, is(true));
    }
}
```

If you remove the call to `setProcessors` then it will detect annotation processors automatically based on the `META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor` files on classpath.

Answer (score 4):

[jOOR](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOR) has an API to simplify [access to `javax.tools.JavaCompiler` as shown in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27062558/521799). You can trigger it easily as follows:

```
Reflect.compile(
    "com.example.MyClass",
    "package com.example; "
  + "@app.dev.ems.support.annotation.HBMModel "
  + "class MyClass {}",
    new CompileOptions().processors(new HBMModelProcessor())
);
```

This is specifically useful for unit testing annotation processors. See also this blog post here:
https://blog.jooq.org/2018/12/07/how-to-unit-test-your-annotation-processor-using-joor

Disclaimer, I work for the company behind jOOR.

Answer (score 3):

This is a link to [my answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3644624/348975).

You could do annotation processing the way you suggest in your question, but you would somehow have to produce the `annotations` and `roundEnv`.

The intended use of annotation processing is during compilation.  I recommend a two step compilation process.

1. Compile your annotation processor and related files in the usual way.
2. compile the other files (using a compiler that supports annotation processing).  You may have to some arguments to the compiler:  the processor path, the class name of the processor, etc.

The compiler will produce the `annotations` and `roundEnv` variables and an instance of your processor.  (Most compilers require that your processor be public and have a public constructor.)  The compiler will then invoke the `process` method.

Comment: Thanks for reply. So there is no way to get these two variable `annotations` and `roundEnv`?

Comment: Of course there is a way to get `annotations` and `roundEnv`.  `annotations = new HashSet<TypeElement>(); annotations . add ( /* your annotations */) ;` and `roundEnv = new RoundEnvironment ( ) { /* implementation */ }` Are you trying to unit-test your processor? You could probably use a mocking framework.

Comment: @emory, I wanna unit test an annotation processor. And a sample would be welcome as this is the first google entry.

Comment: @Snicolas I created an ideone that should help get you started - http://ideone.com/7HhgzI

Comment: I managed it finally. I used this as Inspiration source : https://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2008/04/10/source-code-analysis-using-java-6-compiler-apis.html#invoking-the-compiler-from-code-the-java-compiler-api. I got a sample to unit test a processor [here](https://github.com/stephanenicolas/boundbox). The library is tested using this techique.