# How to compile the annotation processor with Ant?

Tags: java, ant, build, annotations, apt

The question seems to be obvious, but the implementation is pretty hard for me.

My goal is to write *Ant build script* to **compile some classes that require another classes generated** by Annotation Processor.
I have a custom annotations and it's processor implementation (inherited from `AbstractProcessor` class).

As I understand I need to:

1. Compile the Annotation Processor
2. Run the compiler over some annotated classes to generate the new ones.
3. Compile the classes that require generated classes

The code (step 1 & 2):

---

```
<target name="compileAnnotationProcessor">        
    <javac destdir="${OUTPUT_DIR}"
           debug="true"
           failonerror="true"
           includeantruntime="false"
           classpath="${java.class.path}">
        <src>
            <pathelement path="${PROJECT_DIR}/tools/src"/>
        </src>

        <include name="/path/to/annotation/processor/package/**"/>
    </javac>
</target>

<target name="generateFilesWithAPT" depends="compileAnnotationProcessor">
    <javac destdir="${OUTPUT_DIR}"
           includeantruntime="false"
           listfiles="false"
           fork="true"
           debug="true"
           verbose="true">
        <src>
            <pathelement path="${PROJECT_DIR}/common/src/"/>
        </src>
        <include name="/path/to/files/to/compile/**"/>
        <classpath>
            <pathelement path="${OUTPUT_DIR}"/>
            <pathelement path="${java.class.path}"/>
        </classpath>

        <compilerarg line="-proc:only"/>
        <compilerarg line="-processorpath ${OUTPUT_DIR}/path/to/annotation/processor/package/annProcessorImplement"/>
    </javac>
</target>
```

---

Actually, the first task is performing good and compiles the .class file for the Annotation processor implementation. It is stopping at 2nd task.

Ant says: `Annotation processing without compilation requested but no processors were found.`

What am I doing wrong? 
Maybe I should put the annotation processor class in a `.jar`? Or provide a file name with .class extension as `-processorpath` argument?
I tried several options but nothing helps..

---

Notes:

I'm using ant `javac` task instead of `apt`one because [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/apt/GettingStarted.html) claims that apt tool as well as `com.sun.mirror` API is deprecated.
I've also looked through this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3644069/java-6-annotation-processing-configuration-with-ant), but there is no information how to compile the processor in right way.

I'm using:

- Java 1.6
- Ant 1.8.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My usual approach is:

- pack the annotation together with the annotation processor in its own jar
- register the annotation processor via META-INF/services in that jar

Then wherever you have a dependency on your annotations, the annotation processor will be picked up automatically without any additional configuration.

Comment: Is it possible to do the same without placing annotation processor (plus the annotation) in the .jar?

Comment: Well at least the annotation processor usually should be in a different jar than the classes, which are annotated with your annotation, since annotation processing has to be disabled when compiling annotation processors. You can have the annotations and the annotation processors in two separate jars, but then you have to declare a dependency on both of them to process the annotations, which is less comfortable in most cases, I think.

Comment: To be clear, I don't mean that the jar should contain only annotations and annotation processors, but it shouldn't contain any classes which need to be processed by an annotation processor.

Comment: Finally, I put the processor and annotations in the .jar file and specified the path to the .jar file into -processorpath argument. It works, thank you!

Comment: If you register the processor via META-INF/services, you don't need to specify the processorpath argument. Javac will pick it up automagically.